# Keeping React native app opened after opening another app

Tags: android, react-native

I created react native App for android after installing it on a real device
That is the scenario that generate the issue,

- If I navigate to any screen inside the react app (other than the home screen)
- then I opened another app
- and back again to the react app, it back to the home screen not to the screen that I was open before.

That doesn't happen with the emulator, and I can't know if that happen because the react app closed when opening another app or it just reload the app when I back to it.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Add launchMode attribute to your activity in AndroidManifest and try.

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```